# Trying inserting object with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm starting with Laravel and need help,
going straight to the point:

My Models:
Pessoa (Person)

```
class Pessoa extends Eloquent {
   protected $table= 'pessoas';
   public function usuario(){
      return $this->hasOne('Usuario', 'pessoa_id', 'id');
   }
```

Usuario(User)

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent {
   protected $table= 'usuarios';
   public function pessoa(){
      return $this->belongsTo('Pessoa', 'pessoa_id', 'id');
   }
```

My Action Method (Post)

```
   public function salvar(){
    $pessoa = new Pessoa();
    $pessoa->nome = Input::get('nome');
    $pessoa->cpf = Input::get('cpf');

    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $usuario->email = Input::get(email);
    $usuario->senha = Hash::make(Input::get('senha'));
    $usuario->pessoa()->associate($pessoa);
    $usuario->push();
```

Thus persist the two objects but does not save the key pessoa (person) in the usuario (user) table. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`associate()` is for an already existing model.  Since `$usuario` is new, you need to use `save()`, passing the new object to the `$pessoa`'s `usuario` relationship.

**instead of:**

```
$usuario->pessoa()->associate($pessoa);
$usuario->push();
```

**Use:**

```
$pessoa->save();
$pessoa->usuario()->save($usuario);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this solved my problem and I could understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

In order to associate, the foreign key needs to be available or else there really isn't anything to associate.

Try `$pessoa->save();` which will make `pessoa_id` available on the `pessoa` model.

Then you can use `$usuario->pessoa()->associate($pessoa);` because it will now know the `pessoa_id` to save with the `usuario`.